# fill part of a MATLAB struct array using a binary filter

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I can easily fill part of an array using a logical array filter. ie the following works for an array:

```
mydata=[2 2 2];
myfilter=[false true true true false false];
myarray(myfilter)=mydata;
```

I tried the following for a struct array but it gives an error.

```
mydata=[2 2 2];
myfilter=[false true true true false false];
[mystruct(myfilter).myval] = mydata;
```

If I have already filled my struct array using a loop I can access the data with the same filter as follows:

```
mydata=[2 2 2];
myfilter=[false true true true false false];
pp=0;
for p=1:length(myfilter)
    if myfilter(p)
        pp=pp+1;
        mystruct(p).myval = mydata(pp);
    end
end
[mystruct(myfilter).myval]
```

So I can make a loop work to load the data then retrieve the data as expected, but is there a vectorised way to fill part of a struct array?

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed as follows:

```
mydata=[2 2 2];
myfilter=[false true true true false false];
myarray(myfilter) = mydata ;
% make structure

mystruct = struct('myval', num2cell(myarray));
```

Comment: Seems like a start, but it would null out any existing data rather than simply the filtered ***part***. The key use of the filter in the question is the ability to add to or overwrite ***part*** of an struct array.